# How to create a decorator that swallows sys.stdout using unittest.mock.patch function?

Tags: stdout, decorator, mixins, python-unittest.mock

I'm trying to create a Python Mixin for my unit-tests testing functions with return values and `sys.stdout`. I want the Mixin to have a method that will work as a decorator for swallowing the `sys.stdout`, but I haven't been successful so far.

My custom the decorator should:

- swallow `sys.stdout` produced by the tested function
- use the `unittest.mock.patch` function as decorator to achieve that
- not accept any input (to keep the code clean)

My attempt of the decorator:

```py
import io
import sys
import unittest.mock

class StdoutUnittestMixin(unittest.TestCase):
    @unittest.mock.patch('sys.stdout', new_callable=io.StringIO)
    def monkey_patch_stdout(self, original_function, mock_stdout):
        def wrapper_function(*args, **kwargs):
            captured_output = io.StringIO() # Create StringIO object
            sys.stdout = captured_output    # and redirect stdout.
            return_value = original_function(*args, **kwargs) # Call unchanged function.
            sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__     # Reset redirect.
            return return_value
        return wrapper_function
```

Example of tested function:

```py
def foo(some_str):
    print(some_str)
    return some_str.isnumeric()
```

Desired use of the decorater in a unit test:

```py
class Testing(unittest.TestCase):
    @monkey_patch_stdout # The decorator wants inputs - I don't want that
    def test_function_outputs_true(self):
        self.assertTrue(foo("123"))
```

As expected, I get:

```sh
TypeError: assert_True() missing 1 required positional argument: 'mock_stdout'
```

As, I understand `mock_stdout` needs to be there because the `unittest.mock.patch` decorator requires that.

Comment: Do you just want to swallow stdout and not use the output for anything?

Answer (score 0):

I've found out there were two problems:
1) As I was notified by @kdojeteri, thank you, there's a duplication of the monkey patch logic by using the `unittest.patch.mock` decorator
2) the `sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__` line was messing things up. When I saved the reference for `sys.stdout` into a new variable and then used that to reset `sys.stdout` it worked.

Although it's not satisfying one of my requirements, the final working code is below.

The mixin method:

```py
import io
import sys
import unittest.mock

class StdoutUnittestMixin(unittest.TestCase):
        @staticmethod
    def monkey_patch_stdout(original_function):
        """
        :param original_function: Decorated function which is expected to have stdout
        :return: Wrapped function which uses monkey patching for the sys.stdout object
        """
        def wrapper_function(*args, **kwargs):
            captured_output = io.StringIO()                     # Create StringIO object
            my_stdout = sys.stdout                              # Saving reference for sys.stdout
            sys.stdout = captured_output                        # and redirect stdout.
            return_value = original_function(*args, **kwargs)   # Call unchanged function.
            sys.stdout = my_stdout                              # Reset redirect.
            return return_value
        return wrapper_function
```

The tested function:

```py
def foo(some_str):
    print(some_str)
    return some_str.isnumeric()
```

The testing method:

```py
class Testing(unittest.TestCase):
    @StdoutUnittestMixin.monkey_patch_stdout
    def test_wrong_input_outputs_false_with_short_str(self):
        self.assertTrue(foo("123"))
```